# use of ampersand on left hand side of scope resolution operator?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand a piece of code. I know how to use scope resolution operator. The syntax is

```
return-type class-name::operator+(argument list)
```

In my code I have the following form

```
const Rectangle & Rectangle ::operator =(const Rectangle & rhs)
```

I want to know that what is the purpose of using & on the left hand side of scope resolution operator.

Comment: That just means it returns a reference to the Rectangle instead of a copy. This is most likely a duplicate.

Comment: It means just the same as for the argument.

Comment: But we return a reference to the object but Rectangle is a class

Comment: can someone please explain this by giving a simple example

Answer (score 1):

Lets take that *argument*, it's declared as

```
const Rectangle & rhs
```

The argument name is `rhs`, it's type is `const Rectangle &`.

Now lets go back to the return type. The return type is

```
const Rectangle &
```

Note that the ampersand is *part of the return type*.

It might be easier to see if it's written as

```
const Rectangle&
```

(without space between `Rectangle` and the `&`).

That means the function returns a reference to a constant `Rectangle` object.

---

Perhaps it's easier to illustrate using your

```
return-type class-name::operator =(argument list)
```

Placing the function and the above line next to each other (with some added spacing) we have:

```
return-type       class-name::operator =(argument list)
const Rectangle & Rectangle ::operator =(const Rectangle & rhs)
```